# Only last added array in my list

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops

I've got something like this:

```
List<int[]> myList= new ArrayList<int[]>(); 
int tmp[] = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i<anotherList.size(); i++) {                 
        for (int j = 0; j<size; j++) {              
            tmp[j] = anotherList.get(i)[j];                         
        }       
        myList.add(tmp);
    }
```

When I want to print myList, I see only last added tmp. Why?

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i<myList.size(); i++){                  
        for(int j=0; j<myList.get(i).length; j++){                              
            System.out.print(myList.get(i)[j]+ " ");
        } 
        System.out.println();           
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only ever creates one array named "tmp".  You need to move the declaration of tmp inside the first for loop, instead of having it before the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `tmp` array is constructed outside the loops, and thus the same instance is being added to `myList`. To fix, add a different instance to the List at every iteration (eg create the array inside the first `for` loop)